# Create single cloudwatch alarm for multiple Target Groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have around 100 Target Groups.

I want to get alerted when any target group's hosts are unhealthy.

I don't want to create 100 CloudWatch alarms (1 per Target Group).

Is there a way to create a SINGLE CloudWatch alarm that will alert me ANY host behind ANY target group is unhealthy?

@marcin suggested Math Metrics, but no love. AWS has a max of 10 things you can do math on... I have more than 10 Target Groups :(

[image]

Comment: You could probably build an alaram based on [metric math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html) to `sum`  `UnHealthyHostCount` metrics from all your target groups.

Comment: @Marcin, I updated my post with your suggestion.  I was so excited to try it, but then it turns out AWS has a hard limit on the number of metrics you can alert on :(

Comment: Is the limit for `sum` only? Is strange, the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html) write: "Each graph is limited to using a maximum of 500 metrics and expressions, so you can add a math expression only if the graph has 499 or fewer metrics. ". Maybe you have to plot them all, and then use `SUM(METRICS())` as your math expression? Or maybe I misinterpret this?